# count for each row

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

What is wrong with this query?

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT NULL
    FROM words
    WHERE project=projects.id
    GROUP BY word
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) T1) FROM projects
```

MySQL returns 1054 Unknown column 'projects.id' in 'where clause'

Thanks

Comment: What is the table structure? What is the query supposed to return?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does this work?

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM words
    WHERE words.project=projects.id) as pCount
 FROM projects
```

Comment: i was about to post structure details when i saw your post that did the trick! thumbs up!

Answer (score 2):

Your inner subquery knows nothing about the outer query, so the `projects` table is not available.

Comment: how could i make it know? If I'm doing a JOIN projects, it counts every words regardless of the project

Comment: @fabjoa: Could you show us your table structure, and an example from the expected output?

Comment: btw, congratulations on the mySQL gold badge!

Comment: @Pekka: Cheers :) You're soon there too :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to count for each project the number of words which occur more than once.

You can run your subquery for all projects and then use a JOIN to get the rest of the data from the projects table:

```
SELECT projects.*, COUNT(word) AS cnt
FROM projects
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT project, word
        FROM words
        GROUP BY project, word
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) T1
ON T1.project = projects.id
GROUP BY projects.id
```

Result:

```
id  cnt
1   0
2   1
3   2
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE projects (id INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO projects (id) VALUES (1), (2), (3);

CREATE TABLE words (project INT NOT NULL, word VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO words (project, word) VALUES
(1, 'a'),
(2, 'a'),
(2, 'b'),
(2, 'b'),
(3, 'b'),
(3, 'b'),
(3, 'c'),
(3, 'c');
```